# Windows forms application localization problem?

Tags: c#, localization, windows-forms-designer

I have a windows form application. It has textboxs, checkboxs, labels and devxpress xtragrids etc. I need to apply localization to my application. I searched the net and came over some solutions about .resx . But its taking time to apply this method and if i need more languages in the future i need to create a new resx than customize that resx for that form.

Is there any other way to create a xml file so that i or translator change only the xml files.
Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resx files are in XML to begin with. You don't need to "add more resx" when you add language, at least you do not have to add them to your solution/project. What you need is to apply proper build process (I suspect that you build your application directly from Visual Studio, which is not very good idea) - you could use MSBuild to do that. In that case, all you need to do is to place translated files in their right paths and start building.
There are also other localization methods for Winforms applications - for example you might want to try [WinRes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bxdx003%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Comment: But there are a lot of forms in my application. I need to edit too many file seperatly. I want one xml file to use in all resx.